# Attaching mapbox map to livedata

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

My goal is to use MapBox and connect the view to the data set containing GeoJSON polygons. I am already able to get changes from the dataset through a LiveData<List> where Case among other things contains an GeoJSON area.

Now I want to listen to changes to this data set from the ViewModel and bind the results to a specific layer in the map. I haven't been able to find any examples on how to do this as most samples does not use data binding or ViewModel with LiveData.

```
data class Case (
    var id : String,
    var feature : Feature,
    var note : String?
)
```

*Note: The Feature is a MapBox.Feature that implements GeoJSON and it is a polygon.*

I am already able to listen for the changes on the list of cases but haven't figured out how to connect the remaining pieces. **Can you help me on the steps here or maybe point to a good example for this?** A possible answer could be some explanations along with some pheudo code.

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/MyMapView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/jobSelectionJobTitle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:mapbox_cameraZoom="12" />
```

And a bonus question: **I am not sure how much to put in the activity and what to put into the ModelView.**

Comment: I don't fully understand what do you want to do. Please look at this sample https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects  - if you have liveData you the you can observe it and change ui in activity or fragment like in sample. Let me know if I didn't understand your question

Answer (score 3):

This example uses :

- Data Binding
- Binding Adapters
- LiveData
- Kotlin Coroutines
- `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.sources.GeoJsonSource`
- `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.Layer`

The aim to bind `GeoJsonSource` and `Layer` objects to the `MapView` via databinding and `LiveData`.  Also provide a mechanism to remove layers by their "id".  I have deliberably left implementation of LiveData blank as I have no means of how this data is supplied, but provide the mechanism by which this can be achieved.  This mechanism can be adapted to suit your needs.

**Data Classes :**

```
data class GeoJsonLayer(val source: GeoJsonSource, val layer: Layer)
```

**Binding Adapters** (place in separate kotlin file for global access)

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["addGeoJsonLayers", "addCoroutineScope"], requireAll = true)
fun MapView.addGeoJsonLayers(layers: List<GeoJsonLayer>?, scope: CoroutineScope?) {
    layers?.let { list ->
        scope?.launch {
            getStyle()?.run {
                list.filter { getSource(it.source.id) == null }
                    .forEach { jsonLayer ->
                        addSource(jsonLayer.source)
                        addLayer(jsonLayer.layer)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

@BindingAdapter(value = ["removeLayers", "removeCoroutineScope"], requireAll = true)
fun MapView.removeLayers(ids: List<String>?, scope: CoroutineScope?) {
    ids?.let { list ->
        scope?.launch {
            getStyle()?.run {
                list.forEach { id ->
                    removeLayer(id)
                    removeSource(id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Coroutine Extension Functions** (place in separate kotlin file for global access)

```
suspend fun MapView.getMap(): MapboxMap = suspendCoroutine { cont -> getMapAsync { cont.resume(it) } }

suspend fun MapView.getStyle(): Style? = getMap().style
```

**Example ViewModel contract**

```
abstract class MapViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
    abstract val addGeoJsonLayers: LiveData<List<GeoJsonLayer>>

    abstract val removeGeoJsonLayers: LiveData<List<String>>
}
```

**XML Layout** (`layout/map_view.xml`)

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="mapVm"
        type="your.package.MapViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="scope"
        type="kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope" />

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:addCoroutineScope="@{scope}"
        app:addGeoJsonLayers="@{mapVm.addGeoJsonLayers}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:removeCoroutineScope="@{scope}"
        app:removeLayers="@{mapVm.removeGeoJsonLayers}" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Example Activity**

```
class MapActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: MapViewBinding
    private val viewModel: ConcreteMapViewModel by viewModels() // implementation of MapViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        binding = MapViewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).apply { 
            setContentView(root)
            lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner
            scope = lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
                mapView.getMap().setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS)
            }
            mapVm = viewModel
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        binding.mapView.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        binding.mapView.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        binding.mapView.onPause()
    }


    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        binding.mapView.onStop()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        binding.mapView.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        binding.mapView.onLowMemory()
    }
}
```

Gradle file setup (kts - kotlin DSL) :

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 30
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.package.name"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 30
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        named("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Kotlin
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.10")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0")

    // AndroidX
    val lifecycleVersion = "2.3.1"
    val navVersion = "2.3.5"
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")

    // MapBox
    implementation("com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7")

    // Logging
    implementation("com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
}
```

Comment: I am trying to replicate what you did, but I am having a hard time figuring out in which files the code snippets belong. Can you elaborate please :)

Comment: edited to elaborate where extension functions should go (just in a kotlin file), all other snippets already state the top level class - data class, abstract class, class ...

Comment: I am so close now. The only problem is that it cannot find getSource, addSource, addLayer, removeLayer, removeSource and Styles. Do you know what is needed in order for it to recognise these from MapBox?

Comment: I have added gradle file setup .. those referenced classes are part of the mapbox sdk `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style::getSource` etc?

Comment: I am a bit confused now. You seem to be using MapBox version 9.6.1 - but I cannot find any newer version than 9.2.1: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk

Comment: from their documentation : https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/